# My production and uat site is https. In uat we can see set cookies in header but not in production

Tags: .net, cors, web-config

In web config we used requiressl true and httpcookiesonly true .
Uat we can see the set cookies in header through developer tool but not in production

Want to see cookies header on prd and make it secure.

On uat we have allow access control origin *. How to check same thing in production.